# Printing a string to a file in all uppercase, lowercase and reverse java

Tags: java, file, reverse, uppercase, lowercase

I need to input a line of text into the code and have it print that text to the file in all upper came, all lower case, and reverse. I know how to do this with string, but cannot figure out how to get it to print to the file this way. I do not need help with getting the text to print in the output but getting it to print all these ways to the actual PrintToFile.txt without actually inputting it all those different ways.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrintToFile { //open class 

private static Formatter output;

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException { //open main     
openFile();
addRecords();
closeFile();

BufferedReader printFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YoastReginaITM251Project9.txt"));

for (String line; (line = printFile.readLine()) != null;) { //open for 
  System.out.println("Text: " + line);
  System.out.println("Text in Upper Case: " + line.toUpperCase());
  System.out.println("Text in Lower Case: " + line.toLowerCase());
  System.out.println("Text in Reverse Case: " + line);
} //close for

} //close main 

public static void openFile() { //open openFile

try { //open try 
  output = new Formatter("PrintToFile.txt"); //open file 
} //close try 

 catch (SecurityException securityException) { //open catch 
  System.err.println("Write permission denied. Terminating.");
  System.exit(1);
} //close catch 

catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) { //open catch 
  System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
  System.exit(1);
} //close catch 

} //close openFile

public static void addRecords() { //open addRecords 


  try { //open try 
    output.format("%s", input.nextLine()); 
  } //close try 
  catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException) { //open catch 
    System.err.println("Error writing to file. Terminating.");
  } //close catch 
  catch (NoSuchElementException elementExpcetion) { //open catch 
    System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
    input.nextLine(); 
  } //close catch 


  } //close AddRecords 

 public static void closeFile() { //open closeFile 

  if (output != null)
  output.close();

  } //close closeFile   

 } //close class
```

Comment: Use a `FileWriter` and print the String in its incarnations to the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
    String input = "MagicString";

    String upperCase = input.toUpperCase();
    String lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(input);

    String reversedString = sb.reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StringBuilder class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) to create new strings as you like, then print those to file.

Comment: thanks! How would I do that though? Would I print it to my AddRecords or somewhere else? I am not very experienced with StringBuilder and have also found reading about code a bit difficult

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what your goal is. But does this look like what you're trying to accomplish?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677194/dumping-a-java-stringbuilder-to-file

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:

1. Read from a file into a string.
2. Apply toUpperCase() and store it into another string.
3. Apply toLowerCase() and store it into another string.
4. Apply reverse()[own created method] and store it into another string.
5. Then write all these strings into the destination file.

Here is the code by which you can perform the required operation.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class FileRW {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

String filename="filename.txt";
     String upper,lower,reverse,line;
     upper=null;
     lower=null;
     reverse=null;
     line=null;

    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(filename);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
    {  
     upper=line.toUpperCase();

     lower=line.toLowerCase();

     reverse=reverse(line);

     writeToFile(upper,lower,reverse);
    }
}
static String reverse(String test)
{  String returnString="";

   int len=test.length();

   for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
      returnString+=test.charAt(i);
   }
   return returnString;
}

static void writeToFile(String line1,String line2,String line3) throws IOException
{
   String filename="content.txt";


        File file =new File(filename);

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            bufferWritter.write(line1);
            bufferWritter.write(line3);
            bufferWritter.write(line2);
            bufferWritter.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Scanner and FileWriter classes as well. You can try something like this if it works for your purposes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{

   /*
    * Print a string to the output file
    */

    private void print(String s, FileWriter o) {

        try {

            o.write(s + "\n");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


   /*
    *  Convert the strings to uppercase, 
    *  lowercase and reverse. 
    */

    private void solver(Scanner sc, FileWriter o){

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String s = sc.nextLine();
            print(s.toUpperCase(), o);
            print(s.toLowerCase(), o);
            print(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(), o);

        }

    }


   /*
    * Main method 
    */

    public static void main(String args[]){

        File inFile = new File("input.txt");
        File outFile = new File("output.txt");  

        try{

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);
            FileWriter o = new FileWriter(outFile);
            Solution s = new Solution();
            s.solver(sc, o);
            sc.close();
            o.close();

        } catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }   
}
```